# Powershell invoke-computer to a remote that survives a reboot of my local computer?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, disconnected-session

Is there a way to "invoke-command" to a remote computer such that I can reboot my computer and the job will still be running, and I can check the output log whenever I want?

```
    PS> invoke-command -Computer Remote1 -File "ScriptThatRunsFor7days.ps1"
    PS> restart-computer
    PS> # Hey where's my job on remote computer?  Can i see it running and connect to
        # its output after rebooting my computer?
```

Comment: I've removed the second part of your question to prevent closure as "too broad" or "likely to elicit opinion based answers". This is otherwise a good question I will try to answer later today but I am also interested in seeing if someone has a more graceful answer than the cumbersome approach I've used for this.

Comment: Try the `*-PSSession` cmdlets; [Disconnect-PSSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/disconnect-pssession?view=powershell-7.1) sounds like it would work.

Comment: I was doing some testing around that, but had to run. I'm not sure whether a disconnected session can be resuscitated across sessions or reboots. I know that the disconnected session is subject to a timeout but that is configurable when creating the session.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest I don't believe it can. I think `workflows` are meant specifically for that.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I haven't done anything with workflows but suspected they may be useful here. But while workflows can survive sessions and reboots, would a "live" object also retain an operable state on resuming execution?

Comment: @BendertheGreatest we can't even get a _live_ object out of a Job or remote session how could that be possible hehe

Comment: That was kind of my point, guess it was a bit of a rhetorical question lol. But if the session state is retained with identifiers on disconnection, theoretically one could try `Export-CliXml` with a disconnected session object and import after reboot to restore the connection. At least that *test* is possible, but didn't have time to test before I had to head out.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest would love to if that's possible unfortunately don't have a lab for testing it. It would be awesome if it is possible.

Comment: As long as this baby doesn't come tonight I will be able to test this at some point. Otherwise... well I'll have other things to be worrying about 

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it easier to just register a scheduled task that runs the script on the remote computer?
For logging just use the cmdlet Start-Transcript at the top of the script.
I made a script not to long ago to easely register scheduled tasks on a remote computer. Maybe you can try out and see if it works for you?

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    $PSFilePath,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    $TaskName,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    $ComputerName
)

$VerbosePreference="Continue"

New-Variable -Name ScriptDestinationFolder -Value "Windows\PowershellScripts" -Option Constant -Scope Script

New-Variable -Name ScriptSourcePath -Value $PSFilePath -Option Constant -Scope Script
Write-Verbose "Script sourcepath: $ScriptSourcePath"

New-Variable -Name PSTaskName -Value $TaskName -Option Constant -Scope Script
Write-Verbose "TaskName: $TaskName"

$File = Split-Path $ScriptSourcePath -leaf
Write-Verbose "Filename: $File"
New-Variable -Name PSFileName -Value $File -Option Constant -Scope Script
Write-Verbose "PSFileName: $PSFileName"

$ExecutionTime = New-TimeSpan -Hours 8
Write-Verbose "Execution time: $ExecutionTime hours"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {
    $VerbosePreference="Continue"        
    #Removing old Scheduled Task 
    Write-Verbose "Unregistering old scheduled task.."
    Stop-ScheduledTask -TaskName $Using:PSTaskName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName $Using:PSTaskName -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue


     #Creating destination directory for Powershell script
     $PSFolderPath = "C:" , $Using:ScriptDestinationFolder -join "\"
     Write-Verbose "Creating folder for script file on client: $PSFolderPath"
     New-Item -Path $PSFolderPath -ItemType Directory -Force

     #Scheduled Task definitions
    
     $Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At "8am" 
     $PSFilePath = "C:", $Using:ScriptDestinationFolder , $Using:PSFileName -join "\"  
     Write-Verbose "Setting path for script file to destination folder on client: $PSFilePath"
     $Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute PowerShell -Argument "-File $PSFilePath"
     $Principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -LogonType S4U
     $Settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -AllowStartIfOnBatteries -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries -DontStopOnIdleEnd -ExecutionTimeLimit $Using:ExecutionTime -StartWhenAvailable
     $Task = Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $Using:PSTaskName -Principal $Principal -Action $Action -Settings $Settings -Trigger $Trigger
     $Task = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName $Using:PSTaskName   
     $Task.Triggers[0].EndBoundary = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(90).ToString("yyyyMMdd'T'HH:mm:ssZ") 
     Write-Verbose "Trigger expiration date set to: $Task.Triggers[0].EndBoundary"
     $Task.Settings.DeleteExpiredTaskAfter = 'P1D'
     Write-Verbose "Scheduled task will be deleted after $Task.Settings.DeleteExpiredTaskAfter after expiry."     
     $Task | Set-ScheduledTask -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

 } #End Invoke-Command

#Copy script file from source to the computer
$ScriptDestination = "\" , $ComputerName , "C$",  $ScriptDestinationFolder  -join "\"
Write-Verbose "Script destination is set to: $ScriptDestination"

Write-Verbose "Copying script file: `"$ScriptSourcePath`" to `"$ScriptDestination`""
Copy-Item -Path $ScriptSourcePath -Destination $ScriptDestination -Force
```

Usage:

```
Create-ScheduledTask-Test.ps1 -ComputerName MyRemoteComputer -PSFilePath "ScriptToRun.ps1" -TaskName DoSomeWork
```

Answer (score 1):

Something with scheduled jobs.  I'm copying the script to the remote computer using a pssession.

```
$s = new-pssession remote1
copy-item script.ps1 c:\users\admin\documents -tosession $s
invoke-command $s { Register-ScheduledJob test script.ps1 -Runnow }
```

And then later, only when it starts running, it will automatically appear as a regular job on the remote computer:

```
invoke-command remote1 { get-job | receive-job -keep }
```

Answer (score 1):

[vonPryz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/503046/vonpryz) provided the crucial pointer:

On Windows, **PowerShell offers *disconnected* remote sessions** that **allow you to reconnect and collect output later, from any client session**, even after a logoff or reboot - assuming that the disconnected session on the remote computer hasn't timed out.

See the conceptual [about_Remote_Disconnected_Sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_disconnected_sessions?view=powershell-7.1) help topic.

The following **sample script** demonstrates the approach:

- Save it to a `*.ps1` file and adapt the `$computerName` and `$sessionName` variable values.
- The script assumes that the current user identity can be used as-is to remote into the target computer; if that is not the case, add a `-Credential` argument to the `Invoke-Command` and `Get-PSSession` calls.
- Invoke the script and, when prompted, choose when to connect to the disconnected remote session that was created - including after a logoff / reboot, in which case the script is automatically reinvoked in order to connect to the disconnected session and retrieve its output.
- See the source-code comments for details, particularly with respect to the idle timeout.
- One aspect *not* covered below is *output buffering*: a disconnected session that runs for a long time without having its output retrieved can potentially accumulate a lot of output. By default, if the output buffer fills up, execution is suspended. The `OutputBufferingMode` session option controls the behavior - see the [`New-PSSessionOption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssessionoption) cmdlet.

The **gist of the solution** is:

- An **[`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) call with the `-InDisconnectedSession` switch** that starts an operation on a remote computer in an instantly disconnected session. That is, the call returns as soon as the operation was started *without returning any results from the operation* yet (it returns information about the disconnected session instead).
- A later **[`Receive-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Receive-PSSession) call** - which may happen after a reboot - implicitly connects to the disconnected session and retrieves the results of the operation.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

# ADAPT THESE VALUES AS NEEDED
$computer = '???'            # The remote target computer's name.
$sessionName = 'ReconnectMe' # A session name of your choice.

# See if the target session already exists.
$havePreviousSession = Get-PSSession -ComputerName $computer -Name $sessionName

if (-not $havePreviousSession) {

  # Create a disconnected session with a distinct custom name 
  # with a command that runs an output loop indefinitely.
  # The command returns instantly and outputs a session-information object 
  # for the disconnected session.
  # Note that [int]::MaxValue is used to get the maximum idle timeout, 
  # but the effective value is capped by the value of the remote machine's 
  # MaxIdleTimeoutMs WSMan configuration item, which defaults to 12 hours.
  Write-Verbose -vb "Creating a disconnected session named $sessionName on computer $computer..."
  $disconnectedSession = 
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -SessionName $sessionName -InDisconnectedSession -SessionOption @{ IdleTimeout=[int]::MaxValue } { while ($true) { Write-Host -NoNewLine .; Start-Sleep 1 } }

  # Prompt the user for when to connect and retrieve the output 
  # from the disconnected session.
  do {
    $response = Read-Host @"
---

Disconnected session $sessionName created on computer $computer.

You can connect to it and retrieve its output from any session on this machine,
even after a reboot.

* If you choose to log off or reboot now, this script re-runs automatically 
  when you log back in, in order to connect to the remote session and collect its output.

* To see open sessions on the target computer on demand, run the following
  (append | Remove-PSSession to remove them):

   Get-PSSession -ComputerName $computer

---

Do you want to (L)og off, (R)eboot, (C)onnect right now, or (Q)uit (submit with ENTER)? [l/r/c/q] 
"@
  } while (($response = $response.Trim()) -notin 'l', 'r', 'c', 'q')


  $autoRelaunchCmd = { 
   Set-ItemProperty registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce 'ReconnectDemo' "$((Get-Command powershell.exe).Path) -noexit -command `"Set-Location '$PWD'; . '$PSCommandPath'`"" 
  }

  switch ($response) {
    'q' { Write-Verbose -vb 'Aborted.'; exit 2 }
    'c' { break } # resume below
    'l' { 
       Write-Verbose -vb "Logging off..."
       & $autoRelaunchCmd
       logoff.exe
       exit
    }
    'r' {
       Write-Verbose -vb "Rebooting..."
       & $autoRelaunchCmd
       Restart-Computer
       exit
     } 
  }

}

# Getting here means that a remote disconnection session was previously created.
# Reconnect and retrieve its output.

# Implicitly reconnect to the session by name,
# and receive a job object representing the remotely running command.
# Note: Despite what the docs say, -OutTarget Job seems to be the default.
#       Use -Output Host to directly output the results of the running command.
Write-Verbose -vb "Connecting to previously created session $sessionName on computer $computer and receiving its output..."
$job = Receive-PSSession -ComputerName $computer -Name $sessionName -OutTarget Job

# Get the output from the job, timing out after a few seconds.
$job | Wait-Job -Timeout 3
$job | Remove-Job -Force # Forcefully terminate the job with the indefinitely running command.

# Remove the session.
Write-Host
Write-Verbose -Verbose "Removing remote session..."
Get-PSSession -ComputerName $computer -Name $sessionName | Remove-PSSession
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function remote_nohup {
    param(
        [string]$Machine,
        [string]$Cmd
    )       
    
        $job_tstamp     = $(get-date -f MMdd_HHmm_ss)
        $job_name       = "${job_tstamp}"
        $job_dir_start  = (Get-Location).Path
        $job_dir_sched  = "$env:userprofile/Documents/jobs"
        $job_file       = "${job_dir_sched}/${job_name}.run.ps1"
        $job_log        = "${job_dir_sched}/${job_name}.log"
        $job_computer   = $Machine
        $job_cmd        = $Cmd

        # Create Job File
        $job_ps1 = @(
            "`$ErrorActionPreference  = `"Stop`""
            ""
            "Start-Transcript -path $job_log -append"
            ""
            "try {"
            "    write-host 'job_begin:($job_name)'"
            "    "
            "    set-location $job_dir_start -EA 0"
            "    "
            "    write-host 'job_cmd:($job_cmd)'"
            "    $job_cmd | out-host"
            ""
            "    write-host 'job_end:($job_name)'"
            "}"
            "catch {"
            "    `$msg = `$_"
            "    write-host  `$msg"
            "    write-error `$msg"
            "}"
            "finally {"
            "    Stop-Transcript"
            "}"
            ""
            "Exit-PSSession"
        )
        
        try {
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -EA:0 -Path $job_dir_sched | out-null
            copy-Item $remote_profile_ps1 $job_profile 
            
            write-host "Creating File: $job_file"
            $f1 = open_w $job_file -fatal
            foreach ($line in $job_ps1) {
                $f1.WriteLine($line)
            }           
        }
        finally {
            $f1.close()
        }   

        # Create Jobs Dir
        write-host "Creating remote job Directory"
        Invoke-Command -Computer $job_computer -ScriptBlock { 
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -EA:0 -Path $using:job_dir_sched | out-null
        }
        
        # Copy Job File
        write-host "copy-Item -recurse -ToSession `$s2  $job_file $job_file"
        $s2 = New-PSSession -Computer $job_computer
        copy-Item -ToSession $s2  $job_file $job_file    
        Receive-PSSession -Session $s2
        Remove-PSSession -Session $s2

        # Create Persistent Background Job
        write-host "Submitting job to remote scheduler"
        Invoke-Command -Computer $job_computer -ScriptBlock {
            Register-ScheduledJob -RunNow -Name $using:job_name -File $using:job_file
            Exit-PSSession          
        }

        # NOTE: Log file from run is placed on 
        #    remote computer under jobs dir     
}

function open_w {
    param([string]$path, [switch]$fatal)

    try {
        write-host "path: $path"  
        $pathfix = $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath($path)
        $handle = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($pathfix, $false) #false:over-write, true:append
    }
    catch {
        if ($fatal) {
            write-host -ForegroundColor Red "EXCEPTION: " + $PSItem.ToString()      
            exit 1
        }
        return $null
    }
    return $handle
}
```

Comment: As with previous self-answers of yours, without proper framing and an explanation, it's unclear how your answer addresses your own question.